# Remove the ^L (aka \f/FF/form-feed/page-break) character

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How do I remove the `^L` character and the blank lines that come after it on a unix file? I have tried the below and have been able to remove the VT and spaces but am failing to remove the ^L character and the blank lines after it

```
tr -s '\040\011\' '|' <$x>> modified.txt
```

and:

```
tr -d '\013'  <modified1.txt>> $FILENAME
```

Comment: FF is `\014`. `\013` is VT (vertical tab). L is the 12th letter of the English alphabet (14 in octal).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for the [form feed character](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/formfeed.htm). With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can remove it using its octal value, `\o14` :

```
sed 's/\o14//g' file
```

You can also use its escape code:

```
sed 's/\f//g' file
```

Such characters can be entered in the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then the code for the character. In this case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. So, type this:

```
sed 's/
```

Then, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>:

```
sed 's/^L
```

Now, complete the command:

```
sed 's/^L//g' file
```

Don't write `^L` and don't paste it from the above, use the keyboard shortcut I gave.

You could also remove it with `tr`:

```
tr -d '\f' < file
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\f//g' file
```

---

To delete both the `\f` and any blank lines following it, you could do something like:

```
perl -0pe 's/\f\s*/\n/s' file
```

Comment: why the escape code format `sed 's/\f//'` has no g at the end?

Comment: @FranciscoLuz because I had forgotten it. Thanks!

Comment: @FranciscoLuz It would only be necessary to use the `g` flag if you expect to find (and want to replace) multiple matches on any single line.  It does not sound like you have cases like that, from reading your question.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for bringing that up. A small details that can drive you crazy,

Answer (score 4):

With ksh93, bash, zsh, mksh, recent FreeBSD sh:

```
sed $'/\f/,/./{/\f/d;/./!d;}'
```

That will fail if there are consecutive sequences of `\f\n\n...`s though.

With GNU `sed`, you can omit the `$`.

POSIXly (`$'...'` is not POSIX yet, though will probably be in SUSv5):

```
FF=$(printf '\f')
sed "/$FF/,/./{/$FF/d;/./!d;}"
```

Note that the current POSIX spec requires a newline instead of `;` before `}`, but that's actually a [bug in the POSIX spec](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=944#c2720) as not even the initial implementation of `sed` ever required it.

Comment: Why the `$' '`? Isn't it `sed` that deals with interpreting the escape characters? Why use the ANSI escape for them?

Comment: any reason you don't stick a newline in before `}`?

Comment: @terdon, the only escape sequence POSIXly-supported on the LHS is `\n`, none on the RHS. GNU `sed` supports more, though when inside `[...]` that depends on whether POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment or not.

Comment: @mikeserv, see http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=944 The requirement for newline there was a bug in the spec, no implementation requires it (note that the report there is wrong in that you can't have `;` *after* `}`, but it's fine before `}`). Will be fixed in the next version.

Comment: So did you ever find out what *Accepted as Marked* means? That `sed -E` thing has been *Accepted as Marked* since 2012 I think - I think I recall some bugs kicking about *Accepted as Marked* about `[[ ]]` since 2011 or so *(could be wrong about that bit, though)*. I'm also looking forward to `tail -r` - but I can't figure out what *Accepted as Marked* is supposed to mean.

Comment: @mikeserv I suppose that means it will be in the next revision. Probably TC2, if that's what the "tags" field means. [sed -E](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) (since that's a new feature) will have to wait for issue 8. Also, I'm not sure what _Interpretation Required_ as the status means.

Comment: Apparently they invite anybody to join in - at least in part - in their little meetings - via phone or whatever, I think. I've thought about doing it once or twice, but I usually think again when I consider how difficult it is to make sense of their bug tracker and the minutes on those things. On your bug report there's a thing about *Referred to Sponsor* as well - not really sure if it's been and back again already? I have a hard time with that whole system.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed "$(printf '$!N;/\f')"'\n/,/\n./!P;D' <in >out
```

...should work provided a POSIX compliant shell, `printf`, and `sed`.

You don't really need `printf` though if you just insert the character literally. You can usually do it with *`CTRL+V`* then *`CTRL+L`*.

So...

```sh
sed '$!N;/^L\n/,/\n./!P;D' <in >out
```

...where the *`^L`* sequence above is got by doing *`CTRL+V`* then *`CTRL+L`* and represents the literal form feed character.

Comment: Does POSIX sed not support `\f`?

Comment: @terdon - sure, as a `printf` argument. But to a POSIX `sed` `\f` is just `f`.

Comment: Yeah, I was asking for sed itself, but [it seems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) that it only understands `\n`.

Comment: @terdon, to a POSIX sed, `\f` is unspecified, so any behaviour (including rebooting the computer or matching the FF or  character) by a POSIX sed implementation is allowed. `[\f]` is meant to match either backslash or `f` though. POSIX `sed` _script_ that uses `\f` outside `[]` is not conformant. One that uses `\f` inside `[...]` would be but break with GNU sed (unless POSIXLY_CORRECT is on) where it would match a FF instead of backslash or `f` (so it's better to use `sed 's/[\\f]//` if you want to match on backslash or `f`.

Comment: @terdon - honestly the best way to handle that kind of stuff is with shell variables. It's probably why the spec doesn't get into that stuff because it really is easy, and is kind of a no-brainer for any in-depth application anyhow. You'd do it too - if there was some command arg you were likely to reuse often in a shell script you'd put it in a variable once and then expand it when you wanted it. And so `for E in a\\a b\\b e\\33 f\\f n\\n t\\t v\\v; do eval "${E%\\*}='$(printf "${E#?}'")"; done` - puts them all in vars like `$e` and `$n` and so on. And there's no worry about escape support.